# How to write the notation for some indices

Tags: permutations, notation

Let $r$ be a positive integer $\geq 2$. Let $d\equiv \binom{r+1}{2} $.

Consider a function $f: \mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

I would like your help to write in a more compact way the following collection of $d-r$ constraints
$$
f(x,y,z)\geq 0 \quad \text{when $(x,y,z)$ take the values listed in each row of this matrix }  \quad \begin{pmatrix}
x & y & z\\
1 & 2 & r+1\\
1 & 3 & r+2\\
\vdots & \vdots& \vdots\\
1 & r & 2r-1\\
2 & 3 & 2r\\
2 & 4 & 2r+1\\
\vdots & \vdots& \vdots\\
2 & r & 3r-3\\
3 & 4 & 3r-2\\
3 & 5 & 2r+1\\
\vdots & \vdots& \vdots\\
3 & r & 4r-6\\
\vdots & \vdots& \vdots\\
r-1 & r & d
\end{pmatrix}
$$

My initial idea was to write:
$$
f(x,y,z) \geq 0 \quad \text{for each $x=1,..., r-1$, $y=x+1,...,r$, and $z=?$}
$$
but I don't know how to complete $z$. Could you advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Look at the columns $ r-x, r-y, d-z$.

Show that the condition relating these terms becomes:

> $ { r - x \choose 2 } + (r-y) = (d-z) $

Why does this formula hold?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can see that. Using the formula you provided, would you just write $f(x,y,z)\geq 0$ for each $x=1,...,r-1$, $y=x+1,...,r$ and $z=d-\binom{r-x}{2}-(r-y)$?

Comment: Yes, you might want to set $ r \geq y > x \geq 1$ to further simplify it.